# my regex work fine with preg_match, but fail with preg_replace, why?

Tags: php

I need remove any ROW "hidden" (display:none) from string:

```
$s = '<tr style="display:none"></tr><tr style="display:none"></tr><tr style="display:none"></tr><tr><td>A</td></tr><tr><td>B</td></tr><tr><td>A</td></tr><tr style="display:none"></tr><tr style="display:none"></tr>';
```

then I write my regex:

```
$x = '@<tr.*?style="display:none"></tr>@is';
```

I test my regex with:

```
preg_match($x, $s, $Q);
print_r($Q);
```

work fine!

```
Array
(
    [0] => <tr style="display:none"></tr>
)
```

and now I try delete any coincidence with my regex:

```
$Q = preg_replace($x, '', $s);
print_r($Q);
```

fail... :'(

why?

Comment: Use `preg_match_all()` and you'll see that it's matching every row.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to process HTML, use an HTML parser e.g. DOMDocument.

Comment: never use regex for anything HTML, things will break if its `style="display: none"`, `style=" display: none"` etc your need to bloat out the regex to catch everything, learn and use domdocument https://3v4l.org/lqLnD

Comment: @Barmar then what is the correct `regex` ?

Comment: Change `.*?` to `[^>]*` to it won't match across tag boundaries.

Comment: thanks @Barmar maybe a "name" for search this "[^>]" ??

Comment: It's just a negated character class. `[^>]` matches any character other than `>`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the `limit` parameter of the [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) function. By default it's `-1`, which makes it replacing all the found matches. And for your string all the matches are:

```
0-30    <tr style="display:none"></tr>
30-60   <tr style="display:none"></tr>
60-90   <tr style="display:none"></tr>
90-177  <tr><td>A</td></tr><tr><td>B</td></tr><tr><td>A</td></tr><tr style="display:none"></tr>
177-207 <tr style="display:none"></tr>
```

You may see it using `preg_match_all()` instead of `preg_match()`.
The simple regex that avoids it should be:

```
$x = '@<tr[^>]*?style="display:none"></tr>@is';
```

But, as it's advised in the comments if your task is not that simple as the current question, it's not recommended to use regexes to parse HTML since it's to complicated.

P.S. Just in case a good resource to test regular expressions: https://regex101.com

Comment: thanks @[Alex Melnikov] oh god... the regex `$x = '@<tr[^>]*?style="display:none"></tr>@is';` YES work fine, many thanks; unfortunately me not understand when/how use **[^>]**... I need go to read/study :-)